# Jenkins start failed after changing service to be started as specific Windows user

Tags: windows, jenkins

I set up a Windows Jenkins 2.156 and everythings works fine. Some jobs need to access file servers within the local network, so I want to start the Jenkins Windows Service as a specific user with rights to access these locations.
When restarting the service after that change, I am stuck on the  "Please wait while Jenkins is getting ready to work ..." screen.

File failed-boot-attempts.txt is filled with current time stamp.

Any tips on how to proceed to get this issue fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: FSTrigger plugin scans all configured folders during startup.